# How to recover encrypted partition after dd command

Tags: linux, encryption, data-recovery, luks

I wanted to create bootable usb (dd bs=4M if=input.iso of=/dev/sdc) but sdc is my hard disk with two partitions: 1 simply ext4 and 2 encrypted LUKS. After this action I got Windows installed on my hard disk.

How to recover encrypted partition after run dd comand?

Comment: welcome to U&L Stack Exchange! you seem to be missing the end of one of your sentences, and it's not really clear what you've done or what you're trying to do. please [edit] your question to clarify. thanks!

Comment: @strugee If you read “hard disk” for “hard”, it makes sense.

Comment: Time to get out your backup, I would imagine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends whether you have overwritten the beginning of the encrypted partition. The beginning of the encrypted partition is where the key is stored¹. If you've lost that, the data is undecipherable, and the only solution is to restore from a backup.

If you only overwrote the first 4MB of the disk, and if the non-encrypted partition was before the encrypted partition, then you've lost the non-encrypted partition but not the encrypted partition. (You may be able to recover some files from the non-encrypted partition even if the beginning has been overwritten, but don't get your hopes up: it's unreliable.)

If the encrypted partition is intact, all you need to do is find where it started. When you overwrote the beginning of the disk, that overwrote the partition table, which indicates where partitions are located. Get [Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and ask it to locate partitions — it looks for [magic values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) that indicate the beginning of a filesystem or other volume types including LUKS volumes. Provided that the partition is intact, Testdisk should find it and you should be able to recover it.

However, you mention installing Windows; that is likely to have overwritten the encrypted partition as well. If you've installed Windows, just write off the data on the disk and restore from backup.

¹  <sub>The encryption key is not directly derived from your password. Rather, the encryption key is stored at the beginning of the volume, itself encrypted with a key derived from the password. This allows having multiple passwords (keep multiple copies of the encrypted key, each encrypted with a different password) and changing the password without reencrypting the whole partition (just reencrypt the key slot).</sub>